# Add And remove view Dynamically iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

[image]

```
if count != 0 {
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: Int(count!), by: 1) {
        if i==0 {
            let commodity = storeDetails?.storeSearchPickup.storeMaterialsDetails[i]
            let balesPicked: Int = (commodity?.balesPicked)!
            let balesRemaining: Int = (commodity?.balesRemaining)!
            commoditySection.balepickupedlabeltext.text = String(balesPicked)
            commoditySection.balesremaininglabeltext.text = String(balesRemaining)
            commoditySection.commodityLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
            commoditySection.commodityLabel.text = commodity?.materialShortName
            commoditySection.setCommodity(details: commodity!, index: Int((commodity?.materialId)!))
            commoditySection.callback = self
            commoditiesViewCount = commoditiesViewCount+1
            print("commoditiesViewCount\(commoditiesViewCount)")
            self.currentSelectedCommodity = commodity
        } else {
            let commodity = storeDetails?.storeSearchPickup.storeMaterialsDetails[i]
            var commodityView = CommoditySection(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: commoditycontainer.frame.width, height:   CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude));
            self.commoditycontainer.addSubview(commodityView)
            commodityView.setCommodity(details: commodity!, index: Int((commodity?.materialId)!))
            commodityView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            commodityView.callback = self

            if(currentCommodityView != nil) {
                let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: commodityView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.currentCommodityView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: commodityView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.currentCommodityView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: commodityView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.currentCommodityView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([verticalConstraint,leading,trailing])
                commodityheightconstraint.constant = commodityheightconstraint.constant + commodityView.frame.height
                print("commoditiesViewCount\(commoditiesViewCount)")

            } else {
                let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: commodityView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.commoditySection, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: commodityView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.commoditySection, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: commodityView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.commoditySection, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([verticalConstraint,leading,trailing])
                commodityheightconstraint.constant =  commodityheightconstraint.constant + commodityView.frame.height

                print("commoditiesViewCount\(commoditiesViewCount)")

            }
            commodityView.commodityLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
            commodityView.commodityLabel.text = commodity?.materialShortName
            let balesPicked: Int = (commodity?.balesPicked)!
            let balesRemaining: Int = (commodity?.balesRemaining)!
            commodityView.balepickupedlabeltext.text = String(balesPicked)
            commodityView.balesremaininglabeltext.text = String(balesRemaining)
            self.currentCommodityView = commodityView;
            commoditiesViewCount = commoditiesViewCount+1
            print("commoditiesViewCount\(commoditiesViewCount)")

            isSecondViewAdded = true
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to iOS development, but experienced Android Developer
I have One container in which views needs to be added and removed
when I add first view it properly fits into container, when pragmatically add another view below first view it covers another views below the container
Height of both views is `CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude` 
Need to set height of dynamic according to the contained views

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: Autolayout really helps when putting views together in IOS.

I'd recommend studying it in Apple's Doc's.  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: Unrelated, but noteworthy: `for` loops already "do nothing" when the sequence they iterate is empty. There's no need to wrap them in a `if count != 0` statement. Further, `for i in stride(from: 0, to: Int(count!), by: 1)` can just be simplified to `for i in 0..<Int(count)!`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I think there should be something like `if let count = count`.

Comment: @RomanPodymov Yes, put probably a `guard` would be better instead.

Comment: Are you saying you want your "container" view to grow / shrink vertically as you add / remove subviews? If so, you'll have a much, MUCH easier time using a `UIStackView`.